# "tail -s N" does not sleep for N seconds before updating

Tags: tail

The manual for GNU `tail` says

> `-s`, `--sleep-interval=N`
>
> with `-f`, sleep for approximately `N` seconds (default `1.0`) between iterations; with `inotify` and `--pid=P`, check process `P` at least once every `N` seconds

But when I write `tail --sleep-interval=10 -F file_name`
it does not sleep for 10 seconds, it updates it right away. Am I understanding it wrong, or using it wrong?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I would say that the use of "and" in the phrase "_with inotify and --pid=P_" is that of inclusion in a set rather than the logical intersection of both conditions. In computing terms this phrase would be better written as "_with inotify or --pid=P_". This clause then applies as you are using inotify because of the -F flag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The full manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html) describes `-s` as

> Change the number of seconds to wait between iterations (the default is 1.0). During one iteration, every specified file is checked to see if it has changed size. When `tail` uses inotify, this polling-related option is usually ignored. However, if you also specify `--pid=p`, tail checks whether process *p* is alive at least every *number* seconds. The *number* must be non-negative and can be a floating-point number in either the current or the C locale. See [Floating point](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Floating-point.html#Floating-point).

Your system presumably is inotify-capable, so `tail` will use that instead of polling, and since you’re not following a pid, the `-s` option has no effect. You can disable inotify with [the undocumented `---disable-inotify` option](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21265) (with *three* dashes), which will result in `tail` sleeping as expected (thanks to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) for [the suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615967/tail-s-n-does-not-sleep-for-n-seconds-before-updating/615970#comment1151931_615970)!).

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: @satindersingh, and you can use the undocumented `---disable-inotify` option to disable inotify and that `-s` to be honoured. See also https://debbugs.gnu.org/19760 or https://debbugs.gnu.org/21265